# WPF 4 Datagrid with ComboBox

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a WPF 4 app with a ComboBox embedded in a DataGrid.  The ComboBox is in a template column that displays the combobox when in edit mode but just a TextBlock otherwise.  If I edit the cell and pick a new value from the combobox, when leaving the cell, the TextBlock in view mode does not reflect the new value.  Ultimately, the new value gets saved and is displayed when the window is refreshed but it does not happen while still editing in the grid.

The DB table structure is as follows: Employee(int employeeID, string last, string first, string phone); Project(int projectID, string projectName); ProjectMember(int projMemID, int projectID, int employeeID, string role).  A readonly property, FullName, was added to the Employee entity concatenating first + last.  So the view TextBlock displays ProjectMember.Employee.FullName.  The combobox items come from Employee.FullName.

Here are the parts that are making this more complicated.  The grid and the combobox are bound to different ItemsSource from the EnityFramework which is tied to my database.  For this problem, the grid is displaying project members.  The project member name can be picked from the combobox which gives a list of all company employees.

Any ideas on how to tie the view mode of the DataGridColumnTemplate to the edit value when they are pointing to different DataSources?

**Relevant XAML**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="EmployeeODP" />
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
<DataGrid Name="teamProjectGrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource="{Binding  Path=ProjectMembers}"
       <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" x:Name="colProjectMember">
             <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ProjectMemberFullName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <ComboBox x:Name="ProjectMemberCombo" IsReadOnly="True"
                  DisplayMemberPath="FullName"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Employee}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EmployeeODP}}"
                />
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colProjectRole" Binding="{Binding Path=ProjectRole}" Header="Role" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

**Relevant Code Behind**

```
this.DataContext = new MyEntityLibrary.MyProjectEntities();

ObjectDataProvider EmployeeODP= (ObjectDataProvider)FindResource("EmployeeODP");
if (EmployeeODP != null)
{
   EmployeeODP.ObjectInstance = this.DataContext.Employees;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace a combobox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ProjectMemberCombo" IsReadOnly="True"
              DisplayMemberPath="FullName" SelectedValuePath="FullName"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Employee}"
              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ProjectMemberFullName}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EmployeeODP}}"
            />
```

Also the property `ProjectMemberFullName` must raise the event `PropertyChanged`.

Another way - replace TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Employee.FullName}" />
```

You can get rid of the property FullName:

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Employee}">
    <Run Text="{Binding First}"/> <Run Text="{Binding Last}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

But I'm not sure if the entity implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface.
In the second variant the property Employee must call `OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Employee")`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I have edited my original question to provide the DB tables.  Neither approach seems to work though I am still trying some variations.  For the first, the problem is around the SelectedValue since ProjectMemberFullName is just a read-only property, it doesn't support two-way binding.  For the second, the entity supports INotifyPropertyChanged but it still behaves the same way.  Not sure why.

Comment: ProjectMemberFullName is the property written by you. Why can't you change it to a read-write property? Also check Employee property and pur breakpoint inside a setter of the property.

Comment: Making ProjectMemberFullName read/write works.  The setter can even be "do-nothing", so long as it exists.  Not sure I understand all the subtleties and timing of what is going on but that will come.  I feel like I spend more time trying to work around the Entity Framework than having it save me time.  Thanks again for the help.